# How to use third part framework inside my framework? (Swift / iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode9

I am trying to build a Cocoa Touch Framework written in Swift language.

There are cases where we need to use third party frameworks.

What I'd like to do is package an iOS framework (could be a Swift-framework, could be an Objective-C framework) inside another iOS framework (a Swift-framework) to hide the 3rd-party software dependencies and also hide the 3rd-party APIs.

Could anyone help with a step by step? I am using Xcode 9.2.

Comment: Forgetting about the *obvious* licensing issues... why would you do this? I'll admit it - I'm old! I remember a time we used to call something like this "DLL Hell". Frameworks should always be stand-alone IMHO and require nothing more than a particular OS version. Treat your users they way you want to be treated - would you like to try to use a third party framework that "hides" other third party dependencies and/or APIs? And when it breaks *your* app - have to figure out why?

Comment: I'd like to prevent users download dependencies, as my LIB uses another LIB to work, I'd like to deliver everything ready for my user.

I had not been warned about the license problem, but, I think if I distribute my code on the same license type as the external lib and stating its usage would have no problem, or would it? I will search about it!

Comment: First, good luck. One final thought. How do you plan to distribute things? It needs to be an app to distribute through the App Store, so I'm thinking you'll make it available as OSS?